# npm ERROR - Cannot find module './fs.js'

Tags: node.js, npm

Вот появилась такая проблема, при попытке что-либо поставить через npm выдаёт ошибку

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'pm2' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.4
3 info using node@v4.1.1
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module './fs.js'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (module.js:384:17)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (module.js:384:17)
5 verbose cwd C:\Node.JS\PRDB
6 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "pm2"
8 error node v4.1.1
9 error npm  v2.14.4
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module './fs.js'
12 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
12 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`
```

ноду переставлял удаляю старую, в старой 0.12 была та-же проблема, думаю косяк в винде, но где именно ???

Comment: А какую именно команду npm вы вызываете?

Comment: ну например "npm install pg" . y=но такая реакция на любой пакет, попробовал "npm install pm2"  или "npm install express" выдаёт ту-же ошибку

Comment: **Причина**: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27` - `npm` вызывает цепочку зависимостей `fstream`-`graceful-fs` - `./fs.js`, но последнего по запрашиваемому пути нет.
**Решение**: Попробуйте переустановить npm, вероятно у него зависимости от старых или deprecated библиотек

Comment: Это в консоли nodejs (node.exe) или в командной строке windows? Если в консоли node (node.exe) все хорошо, значит нужно добавить переменные окружения для nodejs.

Comment: да все пути на месте были, ноду переставлял несколько раз, и с полным удалением тоже, решил просто переставить винду, это быстрее оказалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переставил винду чтобы не терять время, вопрос можно закрыть